# Debugging in Visual Studio Code with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to setup a debug configuration for running tests in Node app using Mocha.
I have Ubuntu running as a Windows Subsystem for Linux and my Visual Studio Code is setup to use Bash as the integrated terminal.

Here is my `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Launch via NPM",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "test"
    ],
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "port": 5858

    ...
}
```

This will run my tests in the integrated terminal, but will always time out when trying to attach to the debugger, with the following error:

[image: Error message]

`Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858).`

Also here is what it shows in the terminal before it starts running the tests:

```
cd c:\Users\abc\MyProject ; npm test
-bash: cd: c:UsersabcMyProject : No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to make sure it connects the debugger?

Comment: Does it work if you change the port? Try to set `diagnosticLogging: true` and check the log.

Comment: Tried different port. Also `diagnosticLogging` property is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the npm script, too.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xy-controller",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "node --inspect=5859 main.js"
  }
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program via NPM",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script", "debug"
    ],
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "port": 5859
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but when I try that it times out on connecting to the process. The debug console shows this:
`C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd run-script debug`
`Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/7e740d3b-d874...`

Comment: If I try adding `"console": "integratedTerminal",` (which is bash), it gets confused with the paths:
`cd "c:\Users\...." ; "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run-script debug -bash: cd: c:\Users\...: No such file or directory C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd: command not found`